# Validation of Invalid Date Format in my user form using Zebra Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, validation, datepicker

i have added http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/#download zebra datepicker code in my user form page!

it is appearing fine:

Error image on Form
[image]

i am giving you code here, can one check, whats wrong on my code!

rest all my other properties are working fine, only stuck on date format :(
whole project files are uploaded as well here!

**Download:** **dropbox.com/s/wa5hnugwcn5s6ox/project.zip?dl=0**
and i have placed a code as well, which part i am facing a problem!
page rename: user.php

```
private function set_date_of_birth($date_of_birth) {
        $reg = "/^\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}$/";

        if(!preg_match($reg, $date_of_birth)){
            throw new Exception("Invalid Date Format");
        }

        $parts = explode("-", $date_of_birth);

        list($day, $month, $year) = $parts;

        if(!isset($day) || !isset($month) || !isset($year)){
            throw new Exception("Invalid/Date PArameters");
        }

        if(!checkdate($month, $day, $year)){
            throw new Exception("Invalid/Missing Date of Birth");
        }

        //$this->date_of_birth = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
        $this->date_of_birth = strtotime($date_of_birth);

    }

    private function get_day() {
        if(is_null($this->date_of_birth)){
            return 0;
        }
        $date = date("d", $this->date_of_birth);
        return $date;

    }

    private function get_month() {
        if(is_null($this->date_of_birth)){
            return 0;
        }
        $date = date("m", $this->date_of_birth);
        return $date;

    }
    private function get_year() {
        if(is_null($this->date_of_birth)){
            return 0;
        }
        $date = date("Y", $this->date_of_birth);
        return $date;

    }

    private function get_date_of_birth() {

        if(is_null($this->date_of_birth)){
            return "";
        }
        $date = date("d-m-Y", $this->date_of_birth);
        return $date;

    }
```

2) Singup.php

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="cell cell-left">Date Of Birth</div>
        <div class="cell cell-right">
            <input type="text" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" class="datepicker" placeholder="dd-mm-YYYY" value="<?php echo($obj_user->date_of_birth); ?>">
            <span id="dob_error">
                <?php
                if(isset($errors['date_of_birth'])){
                    echo($errors['date_of_birth']);
                }

                ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear-box"></div>
    </div>
```

3) Top.php

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="styles/default.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="scripts/zebra_datepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datepicker").Zebra_DatePicker({
            direction:1,
                format: 'd-m-Y',
                show_week_number: 'Wk'

        });
    });
</script>
```

4) process.php

```
try {
    $obj_user->date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'] ;

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $errors['date_of_birth'] = $ex->getMessage();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a test I did the following:

```
class zebra{

    public static function set_date_of_birth( $date_of_birth ) {
        try{
            $reg = "/^\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}$/";

            if(!preg_match($reg, $date_of_birth)){
                throw new Exception("Invalid Date Format");
            }
            $parts = explode("-", $date_of_birth);

            list($day, $month, $year) = $parts;
            if(!isset($day) || !isset($month) || !isset($year)){
                throw new Exception("Invalid/Date PArameters");
            }
            if(!checkdate($month, $day, $year)){
                throw new Exception("Invalid/Missing Date of Birth");
            }

            $date_of_birth = strtotime( $date_of_birth );

            return $date_of_birth;
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
echo zebra::set_date_of_birth('19-11-2015');
echo '<br />';
echo zebra::set_date_of_birth('19-11-15');
/* 
    and the output was:-
    1447891200
    Invalid Date Format 
*/
```

So the function works correctly but I don't see where in your code you call the function `set_date_of_birth`?

Comment: i have uploaded https://www.dropbox.com/s/wa5hnugwcn5s6ox/project.zip?dl=0 can you check it yourself, i have added set_date_of_birth on user.php where i have set the function... and i am calling the function on signup.php   <input type="text" id="date_of_birth" name="date_of_birth" class="datepicker" placeholder="dd-mm-YYYY" value="<?php echo($obj_user->date_of_birth); ?>">
            <span id="dob_error">
                <?php
                if(isset($errors['date_of_birth'])){
                    echo($errors['date_of_birth']);
                }

                ?></span>

Comment: OK - against my better judgement I downloaded the zip file and have a look through it, especially the two particular files you mention. I can see no reference anywhere to you actually calling the function `set_date_of_birth` though I can see references to a variable / property ( `date_of_birth` ) that gets set by the aforementioned function / method `set_date_of_birth()` ~ The variable / property thus cannot be available unless you explicitly call this function somewhere ( when processing user input ! )

Comment: function is calling private function set_date_of_birth($date_of_birth) {   , $date_of_birth defined on user.php private memeber ... set_date_of_birth and get_date_of_birth set on user.php file

Comment: had another look in `user.php` within `models` - I can see the functions `set_date_of_birth` and `get_date_of_birth` being defined but not getting called / invoked.

Comment: echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST); 
echo "</pre>";
I have tested my form and without class="datepicker", "date_of_birth" is available in POST. When adding the class back to the line, the JS disables the input.

Maybe someone who has used Zebra datepicker might know what is going on. I don't know why it would disable the input.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all of you!

Extra `</div>` was creating a problem while submitted form, now its fixed